# Is there an efficient way for finding the chromatic number of a given graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

On an exam, I was given the Peterson graph and asked to find the chromatic number and a vertex coloring for it.

I spent quite some time playing around with different colorings and incorrectly concluded the chromatic number was 4 because I could not at the time find one using 3 colors.

The answer turns out to be 3 and once I saw a 3-coloring solution I felt silly for not seeing it while taking the exam.

My question is, given a graph and asked to find the chromatic number and a corresponding vertex coloring, is there a better way to find it other than the guess and check method?

Comment: It is NP Complete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Parallel_and_distributed_algorithms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) What I heard is that, it is conjectured that the problem of determining a graph is 3-colorable or not does not have a polynomial time algorithm.

2) [Brooks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) states that any graph that is neither complete nor an odd cycle satisfies:
$$\chi(G)\leq \triangle(G)$$
Thus, Brooks' theorem can be used to deduce that the Petersen graph is 3-colorable.

Comment: This is excellent and exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. I was hoping that there would be a theorem to help conclude what the chromatic number of a given graph would be.

Comment: @user2521987 Note that Brook's theorem only allows you to conclude that the Petersen graph is 3-colorable and not that its chromatic number is 3